# Run Length Encoding for Array

Tags: java, compression

I have been trying to implement run-length coding compression for String array, but I don't get the expected result ):

Here is my code

```
static void encode(final String input) {
        String[] values = input.split(" ");

       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

       String lastElement = "";
       long count = 0;
       for(String e : values) {
           if(e.equals(lastElement)) {
               count++;
               sb.append(" " + count + " ");
           } else {
               sb.append(e);
               lastElement = e;
               count = 0;
           }
       }

       System.out.println(sb.toString());
   }
```

My input : `encode("Smile Smile Smile JO JO");`

The input I got : `Smile 1  2 JO 1`

But I did not expect this to be like this, I want to get the result as :

`Smile 2 JO 1`

Could anyone help me?

Comment: That's not [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding). Run-length encoding takes repetitions of single values like "aaaabbccc" and makes it something like "4a2b3c". It's not LZ77 either. You need to think about how your format will be _decoded_ correctly, before figuring out how to encode it. Your format doesn't really make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if, say, `values[5]` is the same value as `values[4]`, the `if(e.equals(lastElement))` triggers. This will increment count **and then prints it out**. Which is wrong, unless `values[6]` is not the same, then it was right.

Think about it: When you're on the second `Smile`, you have no idea what to do yet. You're delayed by one: One you see the first 'JO', then you know.

Either write code that looks 'one ahead', or write code that remembers what to do for the previous entry and does it once you know it's relevant. It'll be a little more complicated than what you have so far.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: What variables, and some `if` blocks, probably.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing count for every match. "Smile" gets matched two times therefore it is printing 1 and 2. Try to add this condition in else and after looping of String.

```
if (count>0)
{
    sb.append(" " + count + " ");
}
```

Comment: Are you printing a String and then number of counts it occured more that once? If yes, then it should work. You may need to remove statement adding count to stringbuffer from first if condition also though.